# What happens to Jen when she jumps off the cliff?

Tags: analysis, crouching-tiger-hidden-dragon

What happens to Zhang ziyi (Jen) in *[Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crouching_Tiger,_Hidden_Dragon)* when she jumps off the cliff .. she dies? becomes immortal? Just before jumping what does she want Lo to become - a master?

Why does she jump off, guilt?

Comment: at that stage, she was tired of living a double life. she fell in love with being a bandit with the nomads. the bridge was said to grant a wish to those who jumped off. she gives this wish to Lo and dies, falling down into the valley below. it was just a romantic way to end the film, imo

Comment: This might be her leftist way of enlightenment, when she needs nothing in life, so she takes the only thing she has been following all along, the Green destiny sword.