# In the novel, did Jen die?

Tags: crouching-tiger-hidden-dragon

In [What happens to Jen when she jumps off the cliff?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49165/what-happens-to-jen-when-she-jumps-off-the-cliff) Jen jumps off the cliff.

Did she die in the novel? What happened?